# Code returns pywintypes error containing OLE error 0x800a01a8

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-connector, xlwings

I have a program getting data from excel files. I'm using Python 3.11.4 and xlWings.
The data consists of some standard data and some data defined by users input. The excel contains columns with technical data belonging to product id's located at the top of the column. The data is saved on a database that is created before the extraction starts. Information about the data that needs to be extracted are stored in a dictionary, with the headers of the database functioning as keys. For the standard data the value of the dictionary is an array with the found value from the excel, and a string used as a datatype for the creation of the columns in the database. For user defined data the array has two additional elements: the search string (what to look for in the excel) and the address where to find this string. The value in the dictionary that will be saved on the database is updated for every column that is looped through. The code loops through the documents given by the user.

The problem: when extracting data from many files at once, the code returns an error at a particular excel file:

> pywintypes.com_error: (-2146827864, 'OLE error 0x800a01a8', None, None)
> at line 1395 (the last line of the following block):

```
                #Retrieve properties
                for header in headers:
                    if header_basis[header][3] is None:
                        header_basis[header][0] = "not found!"
                    else:
                        header_basis[header][0] = header_basis[header][3].offset(0,i).value
```

headers is an array with strings defining the name of the user defined data. These strings are the column headers of the database and the keys of the dictionary.

The code itself is quite long and has a lot of content that have little to do with this problem (I assume) But the important parts are here (seperated by (...)):

```
def search_productcard_excel(path, families, headers, search_strings, master):
(...)
    #Create dictionary with value and database data type. 
    header_basis = {
        "product_ID": [None, "BIGINT(20)"],
        "doc_name": [None, "VARCHAR(50)"],
        "family": [None, "VARCHAR(50)"],
        "num_of_conductors": [None, "VARCHAR(50)"],
        "type": [None, "VARCHAR(50)"],
        "CSA": [None, "VARCHAR(50)"],
        #"current": [None, "FLOAT(5)"],
        "note_1": [None, "VARCHAR(50)"],
        "note_2": [None, "VARCHAR(50)"],
    }
    for i, header in enumerate(headers):
        #Add the search string and address for manual data too
        header_basis[header] = [None, "VARCHAR(50)", search_strings[i], None]
(...)
    #Create new table
    sql_string = f"CREATE TABLE {temp_table} ("
    for i, key in enumerate(header_basis.keys()):
        if i > 0:
            sql_string += ", "
        sql_string += f"{key} {header_basis[key][1]}"
    sql_string = sql_string + ")"
    cursor.execute(sql_string)
    connection.commit()
(...)
    #Do for all document names
    create_log_text("Start searching documents...\n")
    for doc_name in doc_name_arr:
        xml_files = []
        for extension in ALLOWED_FILES:
            xml_files.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(path, f"{doc_name}.{extension}")))

        #do for all found documents
        for xml_file in xml_files:
(...)
            #Find the start position of the given properties
            for i, header in enumerate(headers):
                search_string = header_basis[header][2]
                #Search for both columns if "&&" is found
                if search_string.find("&&") != -1:
                    char_pos = search_string.find("&&")
                    search_string_1 = search_string[0:char_pos-1]
                    search_string_2 = search_string[char_pos+3:]
                    temp_range = fun_search_string(search_string_1,
                                                   worksheet[PROPERTY_RANGE_BACKUP],
                                                   0)
                    if temp_range is not None:
                        for search_cell in temp_range:
                            if search_cell is None:
                                header_basis[header][3] = None
                            else:
                                temp_result = fun_search_string(
                                    search_string_2,
                                    worksheet[search_cell.offset(0,2).address],
                                    0
                                    )[0]
                                if temp_result is not None:
                                    header_basis[header][3] = search_cell.offset(0,2)
                                    break
                else:
                    header_basis[header][3] = (
                        fun_search_string(
                            search_string,
                            worksheet[PROPERTY_RANGE],0
                            )[0]
                        )

            #Get family name
            header_basis["family"][0] = worksheet["B2"].value

            #for every column (CSA)
            create_log_text("Search given values...\n")
            for i in range(1, MAX_SIZES):
(...)
                #Retrieve properties
                for header in headers:
                    if header_basis[header][3] is None:
                        header_basis[header][0] = "not found!"
                    else:
                        header_basis[header][0] = header_basis[header][3].offset(0,i).value
(...)
                #Do for every product
                for cell in id_cells:
(...)
                    #Add row table
                    #Create sql command
                    sql_string = f"INSERT INTO {temp_table} ("
                    for j, key in enumerate(header_basis.keys()):
                        if j > 0:
                            sql_string += ", "
                        sql_string += key
                    sql_string = sql_string + ") VALUES ("
                    for j, key in enumerate(header_basis.keys()):
                        val = header_basis[key][0]
                        if j > 0:
                            sql_string += ", "
                        try:
                            float(val)
                            sql_string = sql_string + str(val)
                        except ValueError:
                            sql_string = sql_string + f"'{str(val)}'"
                        except TypeError:
                            sql_string = sql_string + "''"
                    sql_string = sql_string + ")"
                    #print(sql_string)
                    cursor.execute(sql_string)
(...)
            #close workbook
            create_log_text("Closing file...\n")
            workbook.close()
(...)
    #close excel app
    app.quit()
```

When extracting the data from only the one particular file where the error returns, instead of doing many documents at once, it doesn't return the error.
Additionaly, before simplifying the code a little, I stored the values in an array separate from the other data (address, datatype and search strings):
`val_arr[i] = fun_search_string(search_string, worksheet[PROPERTY_RANGE],0)[0]`
instead of
`header_basis[header][3] = (fun_search_string(search_string, worksheet[PROPERTY_RANGE],0)[0])`
This did not return any errors.
I got no idea what exactly the pywintypes.com_error is or what the 'OLE error 0x800a01a8' in it means and I have a hard time figuring t where to start because of it. I haven't found an answer on the internet either.

EDIT: I found a solution myself. I suspected it had something to do with memory. So I just set `header_basis[header][3] is None` before updating `header_basis[header][3]` every loop. This seemed to work. I

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you found an answer to your problem, could you post an answer as well (not just an edit) detailing what code you changed and why you think it worked? Reading through the code and internet resources it does seem like the `OLE error 0x800a01a8` occurred due to a memory issue. Also, could you please include your data size (mostly for my own curiosity)

Comment: @PrestonHager  Thanks for the comment! When everything was working about 9500 rows were added to the database. This was with 5 extra columns/dictionary keys for manual data. I don't quite remember at what document the error occurred, but there must've been added at least 4500 rows already at that point. The dictionary value must've been overwritten maximum 1000 times, since header_basis[header][3] is not updated for every row.

Answer (score 1):

I suspected the error had something to do with a memory issue. Perhaps the dictionary unknowingly filled with data as the values weren't deleted but updated. I reset the dictionary value to None before updating it in the loop. This seemed to work. I'm not sure why exactly, because I would've thought that updating a dictionary value (e.g. header_basis[header][3] = blabla) would erase the previous value and would leave no leftover data. Perhaps it also has to do with the fact that a range is stored there.

The following code:

> ```
>         #Find the start position of the given properties
>         for i, header in enumerate(headers):
>             search_string = header_basis[header][2]
>             #Search for both columns if "&&" is found
> ```

Became:

> ```
>         #Find the start position of the given properties
>         for i, header in enumerate(headers):
>             search_string = header_basis[header][2]
>             header_basis[header][3] = None #Empty the dictionary value
>             #Search for both columns if "&&" is found
> ```